# Person like me or People like me? Any difference?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Not that I don't know about singular and plural, but whenever I use this phrase, it always makes me think for seconds as to which I should use. For instance,

> You know, people/a person like me will probably not get invited to her
> party.

I did a quick search on Ngram viewer [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=person%20like%20me%2C%20people%20like%20me&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cperson%20like%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpeople%20like%20me%3B%2Cc0) that both are used (?) Or probably I've just misunderstood and they are used differently, I'm not sure.

Comment: Are you thinking of a category of 'people like you', or do you think of yourself as the only one with some quality that would make you an undesirable guest?

Comment: @KateBunting it's difficult to answer since that's the point of my question.

Comment: Well, 'which you should use' depends on which shade of meaning you intend. Neither is right or wrong.